# How to call PopUp window only once?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. I want to show PopUp window on exit intent only once. I used Lity as lightbox plugin. Lity shoots new PopUp's every time I leave the mouse on the top, even if I didn't close previous one.
How do I control calling function only once?

```
$(document).on('mouseleave', leaveFromTop);

function leaveFromTop(e){
    if( e.clientY < 0 ) // less than 60px is close enough to the top
      var instance = lity('http://127.0.0.1:8000/wait');

      if (!localStorage.getItem('exitintent_show')) {
        instance.content();
        localStorage.setItem('exitintent_show', 'true'); // this is not work properly, I think
      }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!